# In the β-TCVAE paper, can someone help with the derivation (S3) in Appendix C.1?

Tags: machine-learning, autoencoders, variational-bayes, importance-sampling, variational

Paper: **[Isolating Sources of Disentanglement in VAEs](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1802.04942.pdf)**
[image: Appendix C.1]

I follow as far as,

$$\mathbb{E}_{q(z)}[log[q(z)] = \mathbb{E}_{q(z, n)}[\ log\ \mathbb{E}_{n'\sim\ p(n)}[q(z|n')]\ ]$$   Subsequently, I don't follow how they get the following and beyond that:

$$\mathbb{E}_{q(z, n)}\left[\ log\ \mathbb{E}_{p(\mathbb{B_m})}\left[\frac{1}{M}\sum_{m = 1}^Mq(z|n_m)\right]\right ]$$